# Automatically add unnumbered headings to TOC, without using \addcontentsline

Tags: table-of-contents, unnumbered-sections

How do I automatically add unnumbered headings like:

```
\part*{part name}
\chapter*{chapter name}
\section*{section name}
\subsection*{subsection name}
```

to the TOC, without using `\addcontentsline`?